# Using normal or retina image in tabbaritem

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Since I can't put up a screenshot of my storyboard, I'll try to explain:

I have a tabbar controller that has two view controllers. Each view controller is a navigation controller. I set the image of the first tabbaritem in the storyboard to a non-retina image in the storyboard itself. When I run in the simulator, it doesn't pick up the @2x version of the image. I know that there are other questions like this but I have tried all the answers and they don't work. How do I tell iOS to pick up the non-retina or retina image depending on the device in code. I don't want to explicitly tell it. It should do it automatically, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your file names. The file name has to be exactly the same with `@2x` added, but before the file type extension. In Storyboard, you would then just select the simple one.

```
image.png  
image@2x.png
```

Also check that the retina image is actually associated with the target. If in doubt, remove it and add it again.